# GetAsyncKeyState and using System.Windows.Forms doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, get

I have a problem with my "keylogger". Why in this code I see problem with library "using System.Windows.Forms;"

It shows the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>   C:\Users\SoChi\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WpfApplication8\WpfApplication8\MainWindow.xaml.cs 16  22  WpfApplication8

I dont know why. Can you help me?

The whole Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ComponentModel;
namespace WpfApplication8
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
               public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern Int16 GetAsyncKeyState(int vKey);
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            while (true)
            for (int key = 0; key < 255;key++)
                if (GetAsyncKeyState(key) == -32767)
                {
                    label.Content = "kliknales cos na klawiaturze";
                }
        }       
    }
}    `
```

Comment: Why do you need `System.Windows.Forms` in a WPF application? Since WPF and WinForms are two different technologies they usually don't reference each other, so you have to add the reference manually by right-clicking your project and selecting `Add Reference...`.

Comment: Without `System.Windows.Forms` the program is not working. What is bad in this code?

Comment: I got this System.Windows.Forms after creation template

Comment: Well the problem is elsewhere. Your code doesn't reference anything from `System.Windows.Forms` so you should just remove it.

Comment: FYI Since you are running an infinite loop in a button the UI won't be able to redraw itself (thus you won't see the label update). Look into using a [**BackgroundWorker**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Ok i deleted 'while(true)' but now program is working but while i click on the button and on the keyboard in the same time.

Comment: Of course it only works when you click the button. If you don't have a loop it won't continue checking. -- I never said that you should remove the loop, I said that you should use a `BackgroundWorker`.